# How to new a NumberDecimal() in JavaScript Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I tried to run some Javascript NumberDecimal tests in Mongodb3.4, but however the output is never correct, if I used the NumberInt instead, then the result is correct. Does Javascript unsupports NumberDecimal type?

The following is my testing script:

```
    var X=new NumberDecimal("100");
    var Y=new NumberDecimal("100");
    var RTNEqual=(X.valueOf()==Y.valueOf());
    var RTNPlus=X+Y;
    print("Equal=>" + RTNEqual + "  RTNPlus=>" + RTNPlus)

    Output: 
    Equal=>false  RTNPlus=>NumberDecimal("100")NumberDecimal("100")
```

Thank you~

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you going to insert the number decimal in mongo or trying to fetch it in form of Number Decimal?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to plus two values which are all in the form of NumberDecimal, here are the example: 

      L1:{"X" : NumberDecimal("1234.01")}
      L2:{"Y" : NumberDecimal("5678.02")}

How to write script to plus X and Y. 

Thanks.

Comment: where are you trying to add these values? in mongo shell or in a node program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mongo` shell (as at 3.4.5) does not support arithmetic with `NumberDecimal` values. The decimal type is not native to JavaScript, so decimal values in the shell are strings representing the BSON value stored in MongoDB.

As per discussion on [SERVER-19676](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19676) in the MongoDB issue tracker:

> Due to the fundamental problems inherent to doing non-floating point math in javascript, there isn't any easy system to hook into to provide arithmetic support for our types. If/when javascript provides operator overloading, or something that looks more live value types, we may revisit the issue. In the meantime, we aren't planning on re-implementing arithmetic via methods.

However, decimal values are fully supported if you manipulate on the server via the aggregation framework:

```
var X=new NumberDecimal("100");
var Y=new NumberDecimal("100");

db.omnum.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        RTNEqual: { $eq: [X, Y] },
        RTNPlus: { $sum: [X, Y] }
    }}
)
```

Output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "RTNEqual": true,
      "RTNPlus": NumberDecimal("200")
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Stennie.
I did it that way:

```
function addUpDecimalNumbers(a, b) {
    var results = db.DummyCollection.aggregate([
       { $limit: 1 }, // because there would be a result for every document in the collection
       { $project: {"Sum": {$sum: [a, b]}} }
    ]).toArray();
    return results[0].Sum;
}

var first = NumberDecimal(1.5);
var second = NumberDecimal(2.5);
var result = addUpDecimalNumbers(first, second);
print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround could be to do something like this

```
var X=new NumberDecimal("100");
var Y=new NumberDecimal("100");
var jsonY = tojson(Y)
var jsonX = tojson(X)
var RTNEqual= jsonY == jsonX;
print("Equal=>" + RTNEqual);
```